# How to get all token allowances in ethereum in python?

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

Is there a way to get all the approvals granted by an ethereum address along with the contract it granted permission to in python?

I want to obtain them programatically instead of using token approval checker websites.

Tried pulling the data using the requests made by websites like revoke.cash, but getting blocked often.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need an indexed source in any case, whether your own or a hosted on e.g. ette.

From there you can get all tokens the user holds, and then you would get the latest allowance `allowance(address owner, address spender) → uint256` (which is standard for most ERC20 tokens) for every token.

Some indexers (e.g [ette](https://github.com/itzmeanjan/ette#historical-event-data--rest-api--)) allow you to query by event, so you could get all `Approvals`, this is faster.